# Is it possible to navigate to function definition in parent components from child compoennt using vscode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vscode-extensions

I wonder if there is a vscode extension could do the work, or how could I custom vscode `go to definition` or `find all reference` to make it work:

```
function ParentComponent() {
    // funcInParent definition
    function funcInParent() {}
    return <ChildComponent
            passToChildFunc={funcInParent}
        >
        </ChildComponent>
}

function ChildComponent({ passToChildFunc }) {
     passToChildFunc();  // want to custom `go to definition` to go to `funcInParent definition` in ParentComponent
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how this could be possible, the value of `passToChildFunc` isn't known until runtime. Better would be to use TypeScript and then share the type between `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`

Answer (score 0):

The closest keyboard shortcut I managed to find is `Ctrl+T`, 
which is - **Show all symbols** 
[for more shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_keyboard-reference-sheets)